# RxSwift tableView update based on property

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have a UITableView populated with Product models. There are 2 challenges I'm having right now. The first is I have a quantityLabel on the cells which I want to update when the user presses an increment or decrement button on the cell. Currently to do this, I am updating the model and accepting an entirely new array, which triggers the tableView to reload, which isn't ideal. The second challenge is, when the quantity of a Product goes to 0, that cell should be removed from the tableView with an animation. Currently, I just find the index of the product within the dataSource, remove it and reload the table. I'd like to know the proper Rx way to do this. Here's a sample of my code. Thanks!

```
struct Product: Equatable {
  var i: String
  var quantity: Int
  init(i: Int, quantity: Int) {
    self.i = "item: \(i)"
    self.quantity = quantity
  }
}
extension Product {
  static func ==(lhs: Product, rhs: Product) -> Bool {
    return lhs.i == rhs.i
  }
}

class ProductSource {
  var items: BehaviorRelay<[Product]> = BehaviorRelay<[Product]>(value: [])
  var itemsObservable: Observable<[Product]>
  init() {
    itemsObservable = items.asObservable().share(replay: 1)
    items.accept((0..<20).map { Product(i: $0, quantity: 2) })
  }

  func add(product: Product) {}

  func remove(product: Product) {
    guard let index = self.items.value.index(of: product) else {return}

  // decrement quantity, if quantity is 0, remove from the datasource and update the tableView
  }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
  var data = ProductSource()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    data.itemsObservable
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "productCell", cellType: ProductTableViewCell.self)) { row, element, cell in
            cell.nameLabel.text = element.i
            cell.quantityLabel.text = String(element.quantity)
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
  }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your challenges can be solved by using the `RxDataSources` Cocoapod.

Alternatively, you could roll your own like I did here: https://github.com/dtartaglia/RxMultiCounter/blob/master/RxMultiCounter/RxExtensions/RxSimpleAnimatableDataSource.swift

The idea here is to use something (I'm using DifferenceKit) to figure out which elements changed and only reload those particular elements. To do this, you need a specialized data source object, not the generic one that comes with RxCocoa.